# making the color in the plot continuous(if possible, by identifying and outlining boundaries)

Tags: python, matplotlib

given a point in 2D space,

I have a function that can give to which 'zone' that function belongs to.
The zones are numbered '1, 2, 3, ...

Using this function I took a lot of random points in 2D space and colored each zone.
Each of them start from the centre(square) which is the 1st zone(blue)
2nd zone (green), so on from inside to outside. And it looks like this:
[image]

**How can I make this plot look continuous without looking like a lot of points?**(with each zone having a single smooth color)

I've used:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for zone in zones:
    plt.plot(X, Y, 'o')  # picks a different color automatically
plt.show()
```

where zones is a dictonary in the form

```
{zone:[X, Y]}
```

for example:
{1:[[x1, x2, ...], [y1, y2, y3, ...]], 2:[[x11, x22, ...}
where
(x1, y1), (x2, y2),  ... belong to first zone
(x11, y11), ... belong to 2nd zone and so on...

Comment: That's an awesome looking plot as it is!

Comment: ... if you were to give the equation for zone_function(), possibly we could find a way to polygonize the output - then you could draw actual areas, not collections of dots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three quick suggestions:

1. Remove the marker borders (as `Gaby aka G. Petrioli` already suggested).
2. Use smaller markers - so the edge overlap is reduced.
3. Use more markers - so the space is covered evenly (as you increase the size of the markers you will of course need even more to cover the area, anyhow).

Like this:

[image]

From this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data1 = np.random.random_sample((2, 10000))
data2 = np.random.random_sample((2, 100000))
plt.plot(data1[0], data1[1], 'o',markersize=10, markeredgewidth=1)
plt.plot(data1[0], data1[1]+1, 'o',markersize=10, markeredgewidth=0)
plt.plot(data2[0], data2[1]+2, 'o',markersize=1, markeredgewidth=0)

plt.xlim((-0.5,1.5))
plt.ylim((-0.5,3.5))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

It would certainly improve if you removed the black border of the markers..

try `plt.plot(X, Y, marker='o', markeredgewidth=0)`